# How Can I Verify varargs To RPC Calls Before Runtime?

Tags: java, corda, static-analysis

I can make an RPC call in Java [like this](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/master/obligation-cordapp/java-source/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/obligation/ObligationApi.java#L192-L194):

```
        final FlowHandle flowHandle = rpcOps.startFlowDynamic(
                TransferObligation.Initiator.class,
                linearId, newLender, true);
```

The first parameter is the class to invoke and the next three are arguments to the class passed via varargs.

As we can see by the [class definition](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/master/obligation-cordapp/java-source/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/obligation/flows/TransferObligation.java#L64-L67) the args match and the call works fine:

```
    public Initiator(UniqueIdentifier linearId, Party newLender, Boolean anonymous) {
        this.linearId = linearId;
        this.newLender = newLender;
        this.anonymous = anonymous;
    }
```

However, if I add or remove args from the constructor the code will still compile and I will only notice at runtime (or **integration** testing - assuming I have enough test coverage).

The same applies if I pass the wrong args in the first place in the RPC call.
e.g. the following compiles fine but gives a runtime error:

```
        final FlowHandle flowHandle = rpcOps.startFlowDynamic(
                TransferObligation.Initiator.class,
                linearId, newLender, true, 100000L, "Random String");
```

Is it possible to check for these errors with something other than test cases?

e.g. Static analysis using a custom IDEA code inspection or a custom SonarQube rule

**EDIT:** It appears that the Kotlin API has a type safe way of starting the flows (using inline reified extension functions) that the Java API does not, so I have removed the kotlin tag and updated the references to Java examples.

Answer (score 1):

Along with `CordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic` which as you mentioned has a varargs parameter for the Flow constructor arguments, there is `CordaRPCOps.startFlow` methods, which is basically nothing more than extension function for type-safe invocation of flows. 
[CordaRPSOps.kt](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/cd0d5c77247efd4e5108c8cfc5eea35e24a3d3ba/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/messaging/CordaRPCOps.kt#L478)

Comment: I wasn't aware that there were extra functions available in the Kotlin API that aren't available in the Java API so I have updated the question to remove Kotlin references. Sorry! Have an upvote anyway!